# Javascript appears to be saying true == false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js function.

```
function showAttentionItem(sender)
{
    debugger;
    var assistanceRequired = sender.parent().hasClass("assistanceRequired");
    if (assistanceRequired)
    {
        sender.children('.assistanceRequiredText').fadeToggle(0);
        if (sender.children('.assistanceRequiredText').is(":visible"))
        {
            sender.children('.studentPerformanceText').hide();
        }
    }
    if (!assistanceRequired)
    {
        if (sender.parent().hasClass("studentOutsideTargetRange"))
        {
            sender.children('.studentPerformanceText').fadeToggle(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens when I run it is, I hit the debugger line, and step through the code.  `assistanceRequired` is `true`.

After executing `sender.children('.studentPerformanceText').hide();`, the next line it jumps to is `sender.children('.studentPerformanceText').fadeToggle(0);`, inside the `if (!assistanceRequired)` statement!

How could this possibly be happening?

Comment: Just use `if ... else`.

Comment: can you log the value of `assistanceRequired` before the second `if` stmt `if (!assistanceRequired)`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I was previously using `if ... else`.  I changed it when trying to debug what in the world is going on here.

Comment: is `assistanceRequried` actually a `boolean` or is it something else, if it is something else it will never be `falsely`

Comment: can you share the related html and how the function is called.. probably a demo using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)(or any other tool)?

Comment: If the `if...else` doesn't work, then something else may be affecting the variable. Try posting a demo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson yes it's a boolean; it is not used anywhere else in code besides what you see there.

Comment: something else is changing it yea for global scope! without a jsfiddle proving what you are saying no body can help you. `if ... else` is guaranteed to work, that is not in question.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added in a console.log there, and it displayed that it was true.  I can also see that it's true when debugging.  That's the insane thing; right before the `if (!assistanceRequired)` statement I can see that it should evaluate to false.

Comment: Is this a direct copy and paste from your code? If you changed anything, you may have fixed a typo in the second `if` which made the variable name something else, causing it to be undefined (and therefore falsy).

Comment: @ChrisHayes yes it is a copy-paste from my code

Comment: why you are not trying it in jsfiddle and give us the link ?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson ok I will create a jsfiddle.

Comment: JarrodRoberson 's answer worked before I had a chance to finish the jsfiddle.  Thank you all for helping on this bizarre problem.

Comment: @levininja We are all still curious as to what the problem was, if you could be so generous as to finish the fiddle? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is guaranteed to work:

```
if (sender.parent().hasClass("assistanceRequired"))
{
     // do whatever here
}
else
{
    // do whatever ELSE here
}
```

Only one or the other can ever run when coded correctly since there is only one test and it will either be `true` or `false` the single time it is tested. There is no possibility for it to be changed by some side effect you are not aware of, which is most likely what is happening. This is not debatable.

If this does not work the way you want then something else is wrong that you are not showing and without an executable jsFiddle good luck convincing anyone that a fundamental thing like the `if ... else` construct is broken.

Comment: why & how does it guarantee something that the OPs code does not do?

Comment: that is the logical explanation... but OP already said that `if (assistanceRequired){}else{}` is not working... then why should this work

Comment: I did this, and for some reason, it worked...I am still completely miffed about how it could possibly have not worked before...but thank you anyway.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - because they are **incorrect** in their assertion that the `if ... else` construct is broken.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson that is because the OP has said that `var assistanceRequired = sender.parent().hasClass("assistanceRequired");if (assistanceRequired){}else{}` has not worked... so the question is what is the difference between that and your code

Comment: @JarrodRoberson so as developers/engineers what we want to know is what is the difference and why it should work than getting a solution...

Comment: @ChrisHayes - honestly who cares, **they were doing it completely backwards to begin with** that is the **root cause**, this is the correct solution regardless of why or what side-effect was causing their problem, irrelevant. JavaScript is a global scope side effect nightmare, that is the problem. More important is they know the **correct** way to express their logic.

Comment: And I don't know why you keep blaming global scope for problems with a local variable. That explanation is nonsense.

Comment: I did not *ask* I was lamenting the fact that so many people do not comprehend basic fundamental core concepts. That function in in global scope, it is probably being triggered multiple times and they do not realize it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson can you point out any difference between your code and `var assistanceRequired = sender.parent().hasClass("assistanceRequired");if (assistanceRequired){}else{}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - yes, **my code works** what you pasted does not. That is a pretty big difference. The explanation is the the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one scenario to explain what you are seeing.

There's a double trigggering of `showAttentionItem()`, which, in the debugger, is perceived as a single call. On the first call, assistanceRequired is true and on the second it's false.

Comment: could be.. then adding a few logging statements should help identifying that... then too how does the value of the local variable assistanceRequired` change

Comment: I don't see how you can answer the question without a test case.

Comment: The question finishes "how could this possibly be happening?", to which this is possibly the answer.

Comment: then how could the accepted answer solve it.... there too the double execution can happen... also if there is a second execution the control should stop at the `debugger` stmt and the `if` block should execute twice... OP has not stated any such thing

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I'm not going to speculate why `assistanceRequired` should change. Just suffice that it **could** do so between rapid successive calls of the function.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - read my answer for **comprehension**, the test is only done **once** in my answer, **it can NEVER "change" because it is NEVER tested twice!**, thus my **lament about the up votes** doubting the `if .. else` construct. Geez.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I should also point out that I formulated my answer before noticing that Jarrod's had been accepted.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's obvious, but that wasn't the question posed. How could `assistanceRequired` change it's value in the middle of that function? Without any extra information, it's not possible to say why.

Comment: This is certainly a weird one. I am concerned that the obvious `if ... else` answer might be masking the problem rather than fixing it *per se*.